# Replace % and comma in data frame

Tags: r, regex, dataframe

```
 dat <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(3L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
                      .Label = c("0,0%", "0,5%", "0,6%", "1,0%", "1,2%", "2,0%", "2,1%", "2,4%", 
                                 "3,0%", "3,3%", "4,0%", "5,0%", "7,0%"), class = "factor"), 
                       V2 = structure(c(6L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
                          .Label = c("0,0%", "12,0%", "2,0%", "2,8%", "3,0%", "3,6%", "4,0%", "4,3%", 
                                            "5,0%", "6,0%", "6,4%", "7,0%", "7,9%", "8,0%"), class = "factor"), 
                       V3 = structure(c(3L, 6L, 2L, 16L, 2L, 14L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
                          .Label = c("0,0%", "10,0%", "11,7%", "11,9%", "12,0%", "13,0%", "14,0%", "15,0%",
                                            "18,0%", "18,9%", "25,0%", "30,0%", "7,0%", "8,0%", "9,0%", "9,1%"), class = "factor"), 
                       V4 = structure(c(8L, 9L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
                          .Label = c("0,5%", "1,0%","12,0%", "14,0%", "14,3%", "15,0%", "16,0%", "16,3%", "18,0%", 
                                            "19,4%", "20,0%", "22,0%", "22,4%", "23,0%", "25,0%", "28,0%", 
                                            "28,5%", "30,0%", "35,0%", "50,0%"), class = "factor")), 
                    row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to do 2 things:
 1) Remove the `,` with decimal `.`
 2) Remove the `%` symbol

```
sapply(dat, function(x) as.numeric(gsub("%", "", x))) 
sapply(dat, function(x) as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", x)))
```

Both of them are giving me NAs. What is it I am doing wrong here?

Comment: If this is data which you have read to R, also note the `dec` argument in `read.table`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to do this in a single step as converting to `numeric` after removing the `%` is still a `character` vector as there is `,`.  So, use the `as.numeric` only after doing both the operations

```
dat[] <- lapply(dat, function(x) as.numeric(gsub("%", "", gsub(",", ".", x))))
```

---

If we are using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
dat %>%
    mutate_all(funs(parse_number(str_replace(., ",", "."))))
```

Comment: We can do it all at once: `lapply(dat, function(x) as.numeric(gsub(",|%", "", x)))`

Comment: @JilberUrbina Yes, if the OP doesn't want to replace with `.`

Comment: Or `parse_number(., locale = locale(decimal_mark = ","))`

Answer (score 2):

Thought I would add a tidyverse approach:

```
library(tidyverse)
dat <- dat %>%
    map_df(str_replace, pattern = ",", replacement = ".") %>% 
    map_df(str_remove, pattern = "%") %>% 
    map_df(as.numeric)
```

Definitely not the fastest approach:

```
mbm <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(lap = {lapply(dat, function(x) 
                             as.numeric(gsub("%", "", gsub(",", "", x))))},
                  tidy = {dat %>%
                      map_df(str_replace, pattern = ",", replacement = ".") %>% 
                      map_df(str_remove, pattern = "%") %>% 
                      map_df(as.numeric)})
```

This shows that using `lapply` instead of my tidyverse approach is approximately 10x faster but maybe harder for some to understand.